# MFMailComposeViewController address book picker customization

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to customise the behavior of how the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is displayed modally from the MFMailComposeViewController whenever a user presses the '+' icon in the 'To:' and 'Cc/Bcc:' fields?

I want to wrap the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController inside of another view controller before it is being presented modally.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of functionality are you looking to add by wrapping the PeoplePicker in another view controller?

You can display the PeoplePicker with the following code:

```
ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *ab = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[ab setDisplayedProperties:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kABPersonEmailProperty]]];
[ab setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];
[self presentModalViewController:ab animated:YES];
```

You may need to subclass ABPeoplePickerNavigationController depending on what you need to do.

Comment: No. ABPeoplePickerNavigationController is being presented by the MFMailComposeViewController. It looks like I have no control over it which is a PITA.